# I'm using a collection to compare with i/p parameter ,but the last index of the collection is not getting compared

Tags: plsql

```
create or replace procedure save_pod_place_tag1 ( p_START_DATE in      varchar2,
                                                  p_END_DATE   in      varchar2,
                                                  p_USER_ID    in      number,
                                                  p_TAG_ID     in out  number,
                                                  p_status     out     varchar2,
                                                  p_status_dtl out     varchar2) is
v_rec_cnt number;
v_ID      Number;
v_CNT     Number;
type l_START_DATE is table of varchar2(100);
type l_END_DATE   is table of varchar2(100);
v_st_dt l_START_DATE := l_START_DATE();
v_ed_dt l_END_DATE   := l_END_DATE();


begin
v_ID    := pod_unique_val_seq.nextval;
select to_char(start_date,'dd-mon-yyyy'),to_char(end_date,'dd-mon-yyyy')
 bulk collect into  v_st_dt,v_ed_dt
 from pod_place_tag_tb;
  for i in v_st_dt.first .. v_st_dt.count loop
 if nvl(v_st_dt(i),chr(0)) < nvl(p_START_DATE,chr(0)) or nvl(v_st_dt.last,chr(0)) < nvl
(p_START_DATE,chr(0))  then
  dbms_output.put_line('START_DATES are' ||'     '  ||v_st_dt(i));
  dbms_output.put_line('INSERTION IS ALLOWED');
  else
  dbms_output.put_line('INSERTION NOT ALLOWED');
  end if;
end loop;
```

The last start _date is not getting compared and I get the o/p insertion not possible even i am passing proper p_START_DATE

Comment: if you want to compare the last you have to write it like `v_st_dt(v_st_dt.last)`

Comment: bhai i need to compare from first to last not just last ny ways thank u, i have gt the solution

Comment: v_ID    := pod_unique_val_seq.nextval; you dont need to get seq value before knowing that you need to insert data. In that way you wasting position. Becouse if you dont allow insertion you seq value are unused.

Answer (score 0):

I think this in roots is wrong... you cant get compare on varchar2 type expecting  result as date, because varchar2 orders in other way.

example

```
select to_char(sysdate+level,'dd-mon-yyyy') dates from dual connect by level<=100 order by dates;
```

Result

```
01-aug-2014
01-jul-2014
01-jun-2014
01-sep-2014
02-aug-2014
02-jul-2014
02-jun-2014
03-aug-2014
03-jul-2014
03-jun-2014
04-aug-2014
04-jul-2014
04-jun-2014
```

...

```
select trunc(sysdate)+level dates from dual connect by level<=100 order by dates ASC
result
2014/05/25/
2014/05/26/
2014/05/27/
2014/05/28/
```

...

check anonimos block

```
declare
v_date1 date;
v_date2 date;
v_check_date boolean;
v_char_date1 varchar2(200);
v_char_date2 varchar2(200);
v_check_char_date boolean;
v_start_date date:=to_date('01.01.2014','dd.mm.yyyy');
v_count pls_integer:=0;
begin

for i IN 1 .. 300
LOOP
v_char_date1:=to_char(v_start_date+i,'dd-mon-yyyy'); 
v_date1 :=v_start_date+i;
    for i1 IN  1..300
    LOOP

    v_char_date2:=to_char(v_start_date+i1,'dd-mon-yyyy'); 
    v_date2 :=v_start_date+i1;

    IF v_date1<v_date2 THEN
    v_check_date:=true;
    ELSIF v_date1>v_date2 THEN
    v_check_date:=false;
    END IF;

    IF v_char_date1<v_char_date2 THEN
    v_check_char_date:=true;
    ELSIF v_char_date1>v_char_date2 THEN
    v_check_char_date:=false;
    END IF;

    IF (v_check_char_date AND not v_check_date) THEN

    dbms_output.put_line ('v_date1='||v_date1||' > '||'v_date2='||v_date2||' AND '||'v_char_date1='||v_char_date1||' < '||'v_char_date2='||v_char_date2);
       exit;
    ELSIF (not v_check_char_date AND v_check_date) THEN

    dbms_output.put_line ('v_date1='||v_date1||' < '||'v_date2='||v_date2||' AND '||'v_char_date1='||v_char_date1||' > '||'v_char_date2='||v_char_date2); 

    exit;
    END IF;
    v_count:=v_count+1;
    END LOOP;

     IF (v_check_char_date AND not v_check_date) OR (not v_check_char_date AND v_check_date)  THEN

    exit;
    END IF;

END LOOP;

dbms_output.put_line ('count='||v_count); 
end;
```